# AWS code commit how to block put, push, pull access to branch

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to create an IAM policy to block a user from making any write changes to a branch on code commit. It would be great to block read access as well, but I don't know if that is happen. I need them to have access to other branches, but one in particular, read only.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codecommit:GitPull",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:9192919:mybranch"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward",
                "codecommit:PutFile",
                "codecommit:GitPush",
                "codecommit:DeleteBranch"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:9192919:mybranch",
            "Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "codecommit:References": "false"
                },
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "codecommit:References": "refs/heads/prod1"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: I tend to build policies clause by clause, making sure they work as I go. What does your policy do in its current form? What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Regra1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "codecommit:GitPull",                           //flush git pul to your repo yourRepo
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:256267233865:yourRepo"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "codecommit:References": [
                        "refs/heads/main",
                        "refs/heads/master"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "Regra2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:GitPush",
                "codecommit:DeleteBranch",
                "codecommit:PutFile",
                "codecommit:MergeBranchesByFastForward",
                "codecommit:MergeBranchesBySquash",
                "codecommit:MergeBranchesByThreeWay",
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestByFastForward",
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestBySquash",
                "codecommit:MergePullRequestByThreeWay",
                "codecommit:CreateBranch"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:codecommit:us-east-1:256267233865:yourRepo"
            ],
            "Condition": {                                           //blocks push, commit, merge to the yourRepo
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "codecommit:References": [
                        "refs/heads/main",
                        "refs/heads/master",
                        "refs/heads/homolog"
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! Is it possible you can provide more explanation?